# WCF Broadcast through a proxy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am using WCF Broadcast, WCF client directly connects to WCF Server and server broadcasts data to client. I don't know WCF connection have a proxy support or not? WCF Client will connect to WCF Server through a proxy, and WCF Server will broadcast data to WCF Client through this proxy.

If yes, please help me how to deploy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You set the proxy settings in your bindings like so:

```xml
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://..." /> 
</defaultProxy>
```

- `UseDefaultWebProxy` - if set to true, will use the global value HttpWebRequest.DefaultProxy as your proxy.
- `ProxyAddress` - to specify your proxy directly, you will need to set `UseDefaultWebProxy` to false as well
- `BypassProxyOnLocal` - lets local connections bypass the proxy